# indexOf() java in a public method doesn't compile

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors

i just have faced a little problem during defining a public method in a java class. this method ( searchChar() ) is supposed to get the index of a needed substring in the String funcX. As written below:

```
private String funcX;

public int searchChar(char ndd) {
    int gabi = int funcX.indexOf(ndd);
    return gabi;
}
```

The code written above seems to be standard but i got following error:

```
'.class' expected

unexpected type
  required: value
  found:    class
```

hence the class that method lies in it is not used in the main class yet, i couldn't get a compile time error of it.
can anyone help me with this?!

Comment: `int gabi = int funcX.indexOf(ndd);` this is invalid

Comment: `return funcX.indexOf(ndd);`

Comment: Your code isn't standard. Your code is wrong and the compile is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `int funcX.indexOf(ndd)` to `(int) funcX.indexOf(ndd)`, or just delete the cast all together. That's where your problem was. Your method should look like this:

```
public int searchChar(char ndd) {
    int gabi = funcX.indexOf(ndd);
    return gabi;
}
```

Or if you really want to cast `int`(which is unnecessary), it sould look like this:

```
public int searchChar(char ndd) {
    int gabi = (int) funcX.indexOf(ndd);
    return gabi;
}
```

Or as others have said, just write it like this, removing the variable creation:

```
return funcX.indexOf(ndd);
```

Or an even better way to write it would to add another `String` parameter, like this:

```
public static int searchChar(char ndd, String funcX) {
    int gabi = funcX.indexOf(ndd);
    return gabi;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(searchChar('g', "program"));
}
```

Comment: @hsmjml Please accept answer if it was useful for you by clicking the check mark next to the votes. Thank you!!

Comment: sorry my friend @CodingNinja this was my first question and i was new with stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

the second **int** that you have should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
public int searchChar(char ndd) {
    int gabi = funcX.indexOf(ndd);
    return gabi;
}
```

or removing the unnecessary variable creation:

```
public int searchChar(char ndd) {
    return funcX.indexOf(ndd);
}
```